# Triple-Slash Directives between two components

Tags: typescript

I have two components in a AngularJS 1.7 app.

`NavigationComponent` :

```
/// <reference path="../CustomerService/CustomerServiceComponent/CustomerServiceComponent.ts" />

import toggleAside$ = Something.CustomerService.toggleAside$;
export const additionalContentIcon$ = new Rx.Subject<boolean>();
```

In that component I have a function:

```
public toggleAdditionalInformation() {
    toggleAside$.onNext(null);
}
```

In the `ViewDetailComponent` I have:

```
export const toggleAside$ = new Rx.Subject();

public showAside: boolean;

$onInit() {
    this.toggleAsideView();
}

private toggleAsideView(): void {
    toggleAside$.subscribe(() => {
        this.showAside = !this.showAside;
    });
}
```

When I call the function `toggleAdditionalInformation()` from my NavigationComponent it activates the stream and in the ViewDetailComponent the `showAside` property gets set correctly. So it works as intended.

But I also want to create a stream the other way around. When I add:

```
/// <reference path="../../ResponsiveNavigationComponent/ResponsiveNavigationComponent.ts" />
```

To the `ViewDetailComponent`

The function:

```
public toggleAdditionalInformation() {
    toggleAside$.onNext(null);
}
```

Shows a:

> Cannot read property 'onNext' of undefined

Any suggestions what's causing this behavior? Is it because I'm creating reference paths to both files? Is it more like a one way street?

Comment: Which TypeScript version are you using?

Comment: "typescript": "^3.5.2",